# Excel VBA to Highlight adjoing cells in a column that count by 1

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I am needing help with code for excel... I have read and read but don't find help for my specific issues...
I have a spreadsheet that list 3 digit number in column 'B'. It have 30,000 lines.
I need a vba or formula that will look at the column and highlight any numbers down the column that cound by 1...
410
412
441
481
482
499
478
479
480
So, in the column above you will see 481 and 482 are advanced by 1...it would need to highlight 481 and 482...Also, 478, 479, and 480 would have to highlight...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting will do the trick.

1. Highlight Column B
2. Create new Conditional Formatting rule
3. Click "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Enter this formula: `=OR(B1-B1048576=1,B2-B1=1)`
5. Select desired formatting.

Or if you wanted it to highlight anytime 2 adjacent cells are only 1 apart (increment or decrement) this formula will do the trick `=OR(ABS(B1-B1048576)=1,ABS(B1-B2)=1)`

Comment: this does increment by one. I used the data the OP included and it highlighted the numbers the OP indicated should be highlighted.

Comment: Ah, I see. OP was not clear, so I included increment and decrement. I'll add an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I used this...it works...

```
 Sub HighlightCells()

 Dim previousvalue As Integer
 Range("B2").Select
 previousvalue = ActiveCell.Value
 Range("B2").Select
 Do
 If ActiveCell.Value = previousvalue + 1 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 End If
 previousvalue = ActiveCell.Value
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'moves activecell down one row.
 Loop Until ActiveCell = ""

 End Sub
```

Comment: will the data change? if so, you are going to need to clear your formatting before re-running. Also, the use of `ActiveCell` and `Selection` is going to give you performance issues. I'll add that I'm not a big fan of reproducing features built into Excel unless there is a really good reason to do so.